# How to interpret the the fact that sum of two independent uniform r.v. forms a triangular distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know the fact that sum of two independent r.v. forms a triangular distribution and how to get to this from convolution. Namely, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and follows Uniform(-0.5, 0.5), then $X+Y$ have the density $f(t)=1-|t|$ on $(-1,1)$.

But I am wondering how to interpret this strange fact? Any trivial example?

Comment: Why do you think it is strange? And what specifically do you mean by "interpret"? When you say a trivial example, do you mean a trivial example of the calculation showing that it is true?

Comment: I didn't get the point/logic behind the fact, even though I know how to calculate it from the convolution. It's not something I would expect or see immediately. By 'trivial example', I mean some graph illustration or concrete examples(e.g. dice, gamble or something else) to illustrate the point.

Comment: It would probably be easier to think of it in terms of discrete uniform distributions first, because then it is a lot simpler to understand, and then to think of the continuous case as an extension of the discrete one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe one way to interpret it would be as follows: a uniform distribution satisfies the hypotheses of the central limit theorem, so the normalized sum of uniforms should approach a Gaussian (bell curve) in the limit. The fact that the sum of two uniforms is a triangular distribution means that the (normalized) sum of two uniform distributions already better approximates a Gaussian than the original distribution, since obviously the shape of the triangular distribution is more reminiscent of a bell curve than the flat lines of the uniform distribution.

[image]

[image]